# What are all the background soundtracks use in Just For Laughs Gags?

Tags: soundtrack

I want a list of all the famous soundtracks that are used as background scores in the TV show Just For Laughs Gags

[I found a list](http://www.7digital.com/artist/various-artists/release/just-for-laughs-gags-music-vol-2) but I guess it's missing some of the popular tracks (like Flight of the Bumblebee).

Is there a complete list, from all seasons?

Comment: One, on the trombone is Heavens just a sin away. Another is The Singing NUN played possibly on a flute.

Comment: The Pretty Woman saxophone version is missing also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have the Vol. 2 list, so here's the list to Vol. 1.

http://www.emusic.com/album/various-artists/just-for-laughs-gags-music-vol-1/14043095/

Even in these two albums, which are the only two released to the public, there are still 4 or 5 unknown songs missing that have been broadcasted in the gags.

Hope this helps.